# Find the sign of a permutation that interchange the last element with another.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, permutations

Let be $\sigma$ the permutation of $k$ element given by formula

$$
\sigma\begin{pmatrix}1&&\cdots&&(i-1)&&i&&(i+1)&&\cdots&&k\\
1&&\cdots&&(i-1)&&k&&(i+1)&&\cdots&&i\end{pmatrix}
$$
and so we observe that
$$
j=(i+1),\dots,(k-1)\Rightarrow i<j\wedge\sigma(i)>\sigma(j)\\
j=i,\cdots(k-1)\Rightarrow j<k\wedge\sigma(j)>\sigma(k)
$$
and thus we conclude that $\sigma$ has $[(k-1)-(i+1)]+[(k-1)-i]=2(k-1-i)+1$ inversions and so it is odd. So is my argumentation correct? Could someone help me, please?

Comment: Or you can say that $\sigma=(i \, k)$, a single two cycle (transposition), so it is an odd permutation.

Comment: @AnuragA Oh yeah, that's right!